# My additional usb keyboard has strange behaviour when using the windows key

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard

The usb keyboard that I have connected to my Dell E6430 running ubunthu 12.04 with gnome 3 does not open the activites overlay when i press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key on the usb keyboard.

It works just fine when I use the laptop keyboard.

I used

```
~$ sudo /lib/udev/keymap -i
```

To find what the key code was and in both cases (laptop and external keyboard) it is leftmeta.

But when I go and configure keyboard shortcuts the leftmeta on the laptop keyboard shows up as Mod2+Super L and from the external usb keyboard it is Favorites.

Comment: Solved by switching to another keyboard.